# Accessing MCU OP-Memory

Tags: stm32, gcc, stmcubeide

Currently, I am trying to access the mapped IO-memory of my controller (STM32H7A3) in C-Code.

Sadly, the debugger (Segger J-Link via SWD) does not reflect any changes in the IO-Memory (Also the peripherals do not work as intended).
I have used this Code countless times, but it does not seem to work this time....banging my head already :/

I am using the following code:

```
typedef struct __PACKED__ {
  uint32_t Register;
} t_struct;

volatile t_struct* const mapio_XX = (t_struct*) (AddressXYZ);

void special_func(void){
    mapio_XX ->Register = 0xff;
}
```

with GNU Tools for STM32 (10.3-2021.10) on Cortex M7 with FPv5-D16 as Toolchain,

gcc assembler with the flags

> "-mcpu=cortex-m7 -g3 -c -x assembler-with-cpp --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv5-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb"

gnu18 (ISO C18) gcc with the flags

> "-mcpu=cortex-m7 -std=gnu18 -g3 -c -O0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wswitch-default -Wswitch-enum -Wconversion -fno-tree-loop-distribute-patterns -fstack-usage --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv5-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb"

and the GCC linker with the flags

> "-mcpu=cortex-m7 -T"xxxxx\STM32_H7A3\linker.ld" --specs=nosys.specs -Wl,-Map="${BuildArtifactFileBaseName}.map" -Wl,--gc-sections -nostartfiles -nodefaultlibs -nostdlib -static --specs=nano.specs -mfpu=fpv5-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -mthumb -Wl,--start-group -lc -lm -Wl,--end-group"

under the STM-Cube ID 1.10.1.

Does anyone have a guess or a tip?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

The disassembly for

[image]

looks like:

[image: Assembly]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "IO-Memory"? Are you referring to one of the internal SRAM banks, something in one of the peripherals, or some external memory you have possibly connected to the FMC?

Comment: What does the assembler look like for your compiled `mapio_XX ->Register = 0xff;`?

Comment: @brhans I am accessing the IO-Peripherials (USART 0x40004C00 on APB1. 
I also added the disassebly to the question.

Furthermore: Read-Access works fine - so probably no Clock/configuration issue.

Comment: Fixed it - had the reset flag in RCC set in ISR (left-over from debugging)

Answer (score 0):

Had the Reset-Flag for the specific Peripherial Module set in RCC in different file (within ISR). Snippet was a left-over from debugging/developement.